# Is the pdf at infinity equal to 0?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is it always the case that given a continuous probability density function we have:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$$

If not, what are necessary and sufficient conditions so that is the case?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Doug It is necessary to consider the case in which the limit does not exist - not just the case that the limit exists and is nonzero (which you correctly address)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, how could we have limit not existing?

Comment: @Doug For example, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{[n, n + 2^{-n}]}$ would work as a pdf but the limit does not exist.  Or to push that counterexample further, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \chi_{[n, n + 4^{-n}]}$ would also work, but it's not even bounded on any interval $[R, \infty)$.  Edit: OK, so the question says the pdf needs to be continuous; but it's not too hard to adjust these counterexamples to be continuous, by making the components into triangle functions instead of square functions.